# Representing each digit of long number as a node of list

Tags: java, list, methods

I`m implementing a list class of Big numbers (dynamic list) and trying to represent a received long number as a list

for example : 98765432123

will appear as : 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2-3 each digit is a node.
list.

using another class with simple methods (IntNode class):

```
  private int _value;
private IntNode node;

public IntNode(int val) {
    _value = val;
    node = null;
}

public IntNode(int val, IntNode next) {
    _value = val;
    node = next;
}


public int get_value() {
    return _value;
}

public void set_next(IntNode _next) {
    this.node = _next;
}

public void set_value(int _value) {
    this._value = _value;
}

public IntNode get_next() {
    return node;
}
```

BigDecimal class attributes :
`private IntNode _head`

Im using a constructor to receive a long num and represent it as a list by adding each digit to a node.

but having a NullPointerException when trying to add new digit to next node because next node is null.

any help of how to do it without using arrayslist hashmaps etc.. would be appreciated!!

here`s my code where i get nullPointerException error by adding each digit to seperate node.:

```
  public BigDecimalNum(long num) {
   _head=new IntNode((int)num%10); // set node to first digit
   while(num>0) {
       _head.get_next().set_value((int)num % 10); // set next node to next digit.
       num/=10;
   }
```

Comment: Why use such an inefficient way?

Comment: what do you mean by inefficient way ? not using array list ? because its an exercise to understand how these methods are working

Comment: You're using one element per digit. Digits are not natural to binary numbers. Use bytes, or shorts or ints.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can construct a new object of IntNode and use the set_next() method. You should also update the "_head" in each loop. Otherwise you would always update the second entry in the list. I came up with this code:

```
    public static IntNode BigDecimalNum(long num) {
       IntNode _head  = new IntNode((int)num%10); // set node to first digit
       num/=10; // go to second digit
       IntNode digit = _head;
       while (num>0) {
           IntNode nextDigit = new IntNode((int)num % 10);
           digit.set_next(nextDigit); // set next node to next digit.
           num/=10;
           digit = nextDigit;
       }

       return _head;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning an `IntNode` when calling BigDecimalNum?  And why is the routine static?  `IntNode` is something that should be hidden from the user.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be using a string representation of the number:

```
long num = 98765432123L;
String numStr= String.valueOf(num);
System.out.println(numStr);
String[] arr = numStr.split("");
String lst = String.join("-",arr);
System.out.print(lst);
```

which gives the ouput:

```
98765432123
9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2-3
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your `IntNode` class to simplify the example.

```
BigDecimalNum bd = new BigDecimalNum(12345l);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Prints

```
1-2-3-4-5
```

- the `BigDecimalNum` constructor basically iterates over the `long` value and adds the digit to the linked list.
- Since you want the `head` to point to the high order digit, the linked list is constructed backwards, with the head changing each time.
- It is then corrected by repositioning to the first valid node.

```
class BigDecimalNum {
       IntNode _head = new IntNode();
    
    public BigDecimalNum(long num) {
        while(num > 0) {
            _head = _head.addNode((int)(num % 10));
            num/=10;
        }
        _head = _head.next;
    }
    
    class IntNode {
        private int _value;
        private IntNode next;
        public IntNode() {
        }
```

- adds a new value and returns the next node after adjusting the
  new node to set next to the previous one.

```
        public IntNode addNode(int val) {
             _value = val;
             IntNode t = new IntNode();
             t.next = this;
             return t;
        }   
    }
```

I also added a `toString` method to the `BigDecimalNum` class to display the linked list. Since you only have a single `BigDecimalNum` constructor that must take a long it was not necessary to check if the head was null.

```
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(_head._value);
        IntNode start = _head.next;
        while(start != null) {
            sb.append("-").append(start._value);
            start = start.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```